# Resolve php error : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

Tags: php

I'm trying to insert SQL response into .csv file, but when I execute my code, I got this error : Trying to access array offset on value of type bool

This is my code :

```php
$fh = fopen("file.csv", "w");
if($fh === false) { exit("Failed to create CSV");}
$stmt = $db -> prepare("(SELECT DISTINCT nomperso.nom as perso1, rel.relation as relation, GROUP_CONCAT(np.nom) AS perso2, rel.id as idnat, rp.id_personnage as id_perso1, rp.id_maitre_eleve as id_perso2
from rel_perso_maitres_eleves rp
LEFT JOIN noms_personnages nomperso
ON nomperso.id_personnage=rp.id_personnage
INNER JOIN personnages_relations rel
ON rp.id_nature_relation=rel.id
RIGHT JOIN noms_personnages np
on np.id_personnage=rp.id_maitre_eleve
where nomperso.nom like '$nom' and rel.id_langue like '4' GROUP BY np.id_personnage order by relation ASC)
UNION
(SELECT DISTINCT nomperso.nom as perso1, rel.relation as relation, GROUP_CONCAT(np.nom) AS perso2, rel.id as idnat, rp.id_personnage as id_perso1, rp.id_autre_perso as id_perso2
from rel_perso_autres_relations rp
LEFT JOIN noms_personnages nomperso
ON nomperso.id_personnage=rp.id_personnage
INNER JOIN personnages_relations rel
ON rp.id_nature_relation=rel.id
RIGHT JOIN noms_personnages np
on np.id_personnage=rp.id_autre_perso
where nomperso.nom like '$nom' and rel.id_langue like '4' GROUP BY np.id_personnage order by relation ASC)");
$stmt -> execute();
while($row = $stmt -> fetch()){
    fputcsv($fh, [
        $row['nomperso.nom'].".". $row['rel.relation'].".". $row['nomperso.perso2'].","
    ]);
    var_dump($row['perso1']);
}
fclose($fh);
```

Can you help me ?
Thanks a lot.

Comment: `$row` must be false then - you must have an error in your query, run in manually in your DB manager (phpmyadmin, sqlserver etc.) and find your errors

Comment: Whuch of these lines throws that error? What have you tried to resolve it?

Comment: Also, be warned that the given query looks vulnerable for SQL injection to me. Please use prepared statements properly instead of string concatenation to avoid getting hacked

Comment: I tried this request on phpmyadmin and 0 errors were detected

Comment: `$row` shouldn't be bool, or else it wouldn't enter the loop. However, your array keys are wrong. If you `var_dump($row);` inside of your loop, you'll see that the keys won't have the table names on them, just the column names or the alias you set. That would throw a different error, though. (Undefined offset or undefined array key). Which exactly is the line throwing the error?

Comment: when I var_dump($row) in my loop => bool(true). 
And this is the line :  `$row['nomperso.nom'].".". $row['rel.relation'].".". $row['nomperso.perso2'].","`

Comment: When using [`mysqli_stmt_fetch`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.fetch.php), you have to bind the result before you fetch. See the examples on the documentation. Or you can change the code to use [fetch_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) instead.

Comment: Excuse me but I don't understand how can I use bind_result

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mysqli_stmt::fetch` doesn't return a row of result, you need bind columns to variables first.

```
$stmt->bind_result($perso1, $relation, $perso2, $idnat, $id_perso1, $id_perso2);
```

Then each time you fetch a row, these variables will be filled with data.

```
while($stmt->fetch()){
    fputcsv($fh, [$perso1.".". $relation.".". $perso2.","]);
    var_dump($perso1);
}
```

Comment: I've got this error : `Fatal error: Uncaught ArgumentCountError: mysqli_stmt::fetch() expects exactly 0 arguments, 1 given`

Comment: mysqli? I'm just preconceived that you're using PDO, rewrite.